# How to evaluate $\lim_{n \to \infty} \sum_{i=1}^n \arcsin{(u \cdot i/n)}$ without Riemann-sums

Tags: limits, summation

How to evaluate the limit $$\lim_{n \to \infty} \sum_{i=1}^n \dfrac{1}{n}\arcsin{(u \cdot i/n)}$$
Where $0 < u \leq 1$. There is a closed form expression, but I just don't know how to find it.

Without Riemann-summs.

Comment: As you have written it, you will end up with $+\infty$. Do you perhaps mean to divide by $n$?

Comment: Yes. Edited. Sorry.

Comment: You know there is a closed form: $\int_0^1 \arcsin(u\cdot x) dx = \frac{\sqrt{1 - u^2} + u\cdot \arcsin(u) - 1}{u}$. Your question is that you don't want to use the fundamental theorem of calculus.

Comment: Oh, of course. I'll rephrase the question.

Answer (score -1):

Note that

$$\dfrac{1}{n}\arcsin{(u \cdot i/n)}=i\cdot \left(\frac{u}{n^2}+o\left(\frac1{n^2}\right)\right)$$

then

$$\sum_{i=1}^n \dfrac{1}{n}\arcsin{(u \cdot i/n)}=\left(\frac{u}{n^2}+o\left(\frac1{n^2}\right)\right)\sum_{i=1}^n i =\frac{u}{n^2}\frac{n(n+1)}2+o\left(\frac1{n^2}\right)\frac{n(n+1)}2=$$

$$=\frac{u}{2}\frac{n(n+1)}{n^2}+\frac{o\left(\frac1{n^2}\right)}{\frac1{n^2}}\frac{n(n+1)}{2n^2}\to \frac u 2$$

Comment: Your first line is incorrect. And therefore the answer does not match the desired integral.